# Including custom listings style in lower of two-part tcolorbox

Tags: listings, tcolorbox

I am preparing a tutorial for NetLogo, a programming language that does not have a predefined `listings` format. No problem to create one. However, I am trying to present the code inside a `tcolorbox`. This is what I have so far.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\lstdefinelanguage{NetLogo}{
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    alsoletter={-,?,.},
    morekeywords=[1]{to, to-report, end},
    keywordstyle=[1]\color[rgb]{0.25,0.5,0.35},
    morekeywords=[2]{ask, let, set, if, report, ifelse},
    keywordstyle=[2]\color{blue},
    morekeywords=[3]{not, n-of, color},
    keywordstyle=[3]\color[rgb]{0.6,0,0.8},
    comment=[l]{\;},
    commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.75,0.75,0.75},
    string=[d]{"},
    stringstyle=\color{orange},
    morekeywords=[4]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, true, false},
    keywordstyle=[4]{\color{orange}},
}

\lstset{language=NetLogo}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{snippetbox}[2][]{
  enhanced,
  skin=bicolor,
  overlay={\draw[dashed,blue!75!black] (segmentation.west)--(segmentation.east);},
  colback=blue!15!white,
  colbacklower=gray!10!white,
  colframe=blue!75!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  title=Snippet~\thetcbcounter: #2,#1}

\title{NetLogo code instructions example}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

This is a test document for the box structure for code snippet with instructions.

\section{First example}

\begin{snippetbox}{Adding behaviour}
Make various preparatory changes to interface:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Add to section L
\item Amend procedure
\end{enumerate}
\tcblower
\begin{lstlisting}
to setup-patches
  ask patches [ set popn 2000 + random 10000 ]
  ask n-of 3 patches [ set popn 1000000 * (3 + random 3) ]
  set max-popn max [popn] of patches
end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{snippetbox}

\end{document}
```

This works fine. However, I am forced to specify the `lstlisting` environment within the \tcblower section. I tried to put it in the `tcolorbox` specification and the code became plain text.

There will be about 30 of these boxes in the tutorial, all with identical format. Is there a way to use a custom language specification or should I just continue to do it this way?

Comment: In the tcolorbox manual there is how to make box plus listings envs, you need the listings tcolorbox library to be loaded, there is then also an extra tcolorbox option that you can pass næon your listings settings to, so no need for this dublication. However I've never tried that with a split tcolorbox, so I'm not sure if that is supported.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I know I can make a box with the `listings`, but I need `listings` to apply only to the lower segment. That's what I can't figure out how to do.

Comment: Perhaps it would be an idea to make the title more precise then. As it sits now it is rather easy, until one actually read the boby of the question. That two part style ought to be a part of the title.

Comment: okay. have done so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tcolorbox` was initially developed to type `LaTeX`+result boxes, therefore a `tcblisting` box, by default shows `LaTeX` code in one part and the result on the other part.

But it's also possible to define `listing` boxes where one part shows the code and the other part shows some other thing like regular text or images. That's why options `listing and comment`, `comment and listing`, `listing and image` and `image and listing` ar provided.

For this particular case you can use `comment and listing` where upper part is filled with some text and lower part whit a particular code fragment.

Folowing you'll find your code with some little changes:

1. `\newtcolorbox` has been replaced for `\newtcblisting`
2. A third parameter has been added to include the `comment` contents (previous upper part). See `comment={#3}` inside options list.
3. Option `comment and listing` has been added
4. Option `listing options={language=NetLogo}` has been included to apply NetLogo language format to the code
5. In `snippetbox` environment, upper part has been included like thir parameter
6. In `snippetbox`, `tcblisting` environment has been deleted in lower box.

That's all

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\lstdefinelanguage{NetLogo}{
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    alsoletter={-,?,.},
    morekeywords=[1]{to, to-report, end},
    keywordstyle=[1]\color[rgb]{0.25,0.5,0.35},
    morekeywords=[2]{ask, let, set, if, report, ifelse},
    keywordstyle=[2]\color{blue},
    morekeywords=[3]{not, n-of, color},
    keywordstyle=[3]\color[rgb]{0.6,0,0.8},
    comment=[l]{\;},
    commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.75,0.75,0.75},
    string=[d]{"},
    stringstyle=\color{orange},
    morekeywords=[4]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, true, false},
    keywordstyle=[4]{\color{orange}},
}

\lstset{language=NetLogo}

\newtcblisting[auto counter,number within=section]{snippetbox}[3][]{
  enhanced,
  skin=bicolor,
  overlay={\draw[dashed,blue!75!black] (segmentation.west)--(segmentation.east);},
  colback=blue!15!white,
  colbacklower=gray!10!white,
  colframe=blue!75!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  title=Snippet~\thetcbcounter: #2,
  comment and listing,
  comment={#3},
  listing options={language=NetLogo},
  #1}

\title{NetLogo code instructions example}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

This is a test document for the box structure for code snippet with instructions.

\section{First example}

\begin{snippetbox}{Adding behaviour}
{Make various preparatory changes to interface:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Add to section L
\item Amend procedure
\end{enumerate}}
to setup-patches
  ask patches [ set popn 2000 + random 10000 ]
  ask n-of 3 patches [ set popn 1000000 * (3 + random 3) ]
  set max-popn max [popn] of patches
end
\end{snippetbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The `comment and listing` was the bit I hadn't been able to find.